# Passing json to html table: Data all in a single row

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table

I'm trying to pass json data from a php file into an html table. I got it to work but all of my data is being passed into a single row. How do make it so each value is placed into a new row?

Json:

```
{"users":[{"key":["3108","3098","3039","3033","2508"]}]}
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url="localhost/testfile.php";
var table='<table>';
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    $.each( data.users, function( index, item){
            table+="<thead><tr><th>Key</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>"+item.key+"</td></tr></tbody>";
            table+='</table>';
            $("#jsondata").html( table );
```

Update:
If in users i have more than one entry would the correct formatting be:

```
$.each(data.users, function(index, item) { 
 table += "<tr><td>" + item.key + "</td>"+"<td>" + item.x + "</td></tr>"
```

Or am I getting the format wrong?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the table tag outside the loop (correct). You should also create the `thead` and title row, then only create the `tr` rows in your loop. Your second problem is that you're setting the `#jsondata` div's HTML **in every iteration** of the loop. You should set that after the loop:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    var table = '<table><thead><tr><th>Key</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    $.each( data.users, function( index, item){
            table += "<tr><td>"+item.key+"</td></tr>";
    });
    // after the loop, close your tbody and table tags
    table += '</tbody></table>';
    // then AFTER the loop, you set the data to the table.
    $("#jsondata").html( table );
});
```

**Edit:** you aren't getting the correct data, let's look at your JSON structure:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "key": [
                "3108",
                "3098",
                "3039",
                "3033",
                "2508"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So you can see from the "pretty" JSON above that you actually have two levels of arrays, so your loops need to accommodate that. If you are only expecting `users` to have one entry, being `key`, then simply change your `$.each()` to this:

```
$.each(data.users.key, function(index, item) {
    table += "<tr><td>" + item + "</td></tr>";
});
```

Comment: I made the changes mentioned. I still get all the data in the same row:  <td>3108,3098,3039,3033,3031</td>

Comment: You sir are right! I was starting to think it was a data structure issue. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry 1 follow up question. If in users i have more than one entry would the correct formatting be: $.each(data.users, function(index, item) { table += "<tr><td>" + item.key + "</td>"+"<td>" + item.x + "</td></tr>";

Comment: Multiple keys arrays inside users? You'd need to do two nested loops

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
$(document).ready(function(){
           var url="localhost/testfile.php";
           var tableHeaders='<tr><th>Key</th></tr>';
           var tableBody = '';
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        $.each(data.users, function( index, item){
                tableBody+="<tr><td>"+item.key+"</td></tr>";
        });
    });
    //Adding headers to the table
    $("table thead").html(tableHeaders);
    //Adding rows to the table
    $("table tbody").html(tableBody);
});
</script>

<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```